# QR factorization of a complex matrix

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

I am looking for an algorithm for factorizing $n \times n$ matrices of complex elements $a + bi$.
My implementation of the Graham-Schmidt process follows [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Using_the_Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) and always works in the case of $b = 0$ and fails otherwise.
I defined the inner product for complex vectors as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors).

EDIT: Examples and code

QR factorization of $\begin{bmatrix}3i&2-2i\\4+7i&-1+5i\end{bmatrix}$ produces $Q=\begin{bmatrix}0.35i&0.17-0.46i\\0.46+0.81i&-0.66+0.57i\end{bmatrix}$ and $R=\begin{bmatrix}-4.88+6.51i&-3.84+2.21i\\-5.27-1.8i&-2.77-5.13i\end{bmatrix}$, which not only isn't MATLAB's result, it's not even correct - they don't multiply to produce A.

```
public Double innerProd(Matrix v, Matrix w){
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.numRows(); i++){
        sum += v.getElement(i,0)*w.getElement(i,0).conjugate();
    }
    return sum;
}

public Matrix proj(Matrix u, Matrix a){
    return u.scalarMult(innerProd(u,a)/innerProd(u,u));
}

public Matrix[] QR(Matrix X){
    ArrayList<Matrix> U = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Matrix> E = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Matrix> A = new ArrayList();
    for (int j = 0; j < X.numCols; j++) {
        Matrix a = X.getCol(j);
        Matrix u = a.duplicate();
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
            u = u.subtract((proj(U.get(k), a);
        }
        U.add(u);
        E.add(u.scalarDivide(u.mag()));
        int z = 0;
        do {
            a = a.add(E.get(z).scalarMult(innerProd(E.get(z), a)));
            z++;
        } while (z < j);
        A.add(a);
    }
    Matrix Q = new Matrix(X.numRows, X.numCols);
    for (int j = 0; j < X.numCols; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < X.numRows; i++)
            Q.setElement(E.get(j).getElement(i, 0), i, j);
    }
    return new Matrix[]{Q, Q.transpose().mult(this)};
}
```

Comment: The Graham-Schmidt process should work for any finite set of linearly independent vectors in an inner product space. Maybe you can edit your question to include your code.

Comment: I can't see what you've done codewise, but the first link defines $\mathrm{proj}_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{a}$ as $\dfrac{\color{red}{\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{a}\rangle}}{\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}\rangle}\mathbf{u}$. This is fine as this page also defines $\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{a}\rangle$ as $\mathbf{u}^{*}\mathbf{a}\, (= \sum_{k}\overline{u_{k}}a_{k})$. However, if you are using the definition of the inner product provided in your second link, this is $\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{a}\rangle = \sum_{k}u_{k}\overline{a_{k}}$, which is the *conjugate* of the definition in the first link.

Comment: In other words, make sure that you are using consistent definitions of the projection and inner product.

Comment: Schmidt's first name was Erhard, not Graham... :)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth My implementation of projection is consistent with my implementation of the inner product - which is to say inconsistent with the definition of projection in the first link.

Comment: OK. Maybe it will be hard to say what's wrong with it then unless we can see the code or examples. If you are using the projection formula in the first link though, then your inner product should be *con*sistent with the definition in the first link.